# Suppress heatmap non-maxima in segmentation with UNet

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I'm using U-Net for image segmentation.

The model was trained with images that could contain up to 4 different classes. The train classes are never overlapping.

The output of the UNet is a heatmap (with float values between 0 and 1) for each of these 4 classes.

Now, I have 2 problems:

- for a certain class, how do I segment (draw contours) in the original image only for the points where the heatmap has significant values? (In the image below an example: the values in the centre are significant, while the values on the left aren't. If I draw the segmentation of the entire image without any additional operation, both are considered.)

[image]

- downstream of the first point, how do I avoid that in the original image the contours of two superimposed classes are drawn? (maybe by drawing only the one that has higher values in the corresponding heatmap)

Comment: Obtaining an uncertainty measurement of neural network outputs is still an open problem. The usual heuristic is to fix a threshold on the output. To avoid superimposed classes, only the class with the highest values are considered as you mentioned, sometimes with conditional random fields to enforce label agreement between neighboring pixels.

Comment: @JoOkuma can you explain to me better what you mean when you say "sometimes with conditional random fields to enforce label agreement between neighboring pixels"?

Comment: These ideas are presented in these articles http://liangchiehchen.com/projects/DeepLab.html